# how to unit test a multi-domain cookie based javascript library?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I would like to set up a kind of google analytics like javascript library.

I would like to write unit tests for this library that will be cookie intensive on a multi-domain basis.

This seems hard to test because I cannot find a way to use the javascript unit test framework i know for multi-page load tests (domain A.B.com changes location to C.D.com or to E.B.com ...)

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a terrific answer with Node.js [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) project.

Linked to one of the Node.js testing frameworks it shoud lead to an elegant solution.

maybe not totally real-life-browser based but elegant nonetheless.